# Selecting particular data with a particular string at-first

Tags: string-manipulation, data

I have a dataset and I want to select the only data that starting with C_i (where "i" is a numeric with variability).
Here is my dataset:

```
     data={"C3", "O3", "H3'", "H3", "C4", "H4A", "H4B", "C5", "C6", "H6", "C7", \
"H7A", "H7B", "C8", "H8", "C14", "H14", "C15", "H15A", "H15B", "C16", \
"H16A", "H16B", "C17", "H17", "C13", "C18", "H18A", "H18B", "H18C", \
"C12", "H12A", "H12B", "C11", "H11A", "H11B", "C9", "H9", "C10", \
"C19", "H19A", "H19B", "H19C", "C1", "H1A", "H1B", "C2", "H2A", \
"H2B", "C20", "H20", "C21", "H21A", "H21B", "H21C", "C22", "H22A", \
"H22B", "C23", "H23A", "H23B", "C24", "H24A", "H24B", "C25", "H25", \
"C26", "H26A", "H26B", "H26C", "C27", "H27A", "H27B", "H27C"}
```

I have tried with this way:

```
Select[data, # == "Ci" &]
```

But it does not work. My code only works when I put any specific value of "i" (like "i"=3), but I need all at once.
Any suggestion will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another answer, which is slightly different from the first answer.`Select[data, StringStartsQ["C"]]`

Output: {"C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", 
"C13", "C18", "C12", "C11", "C9", "C10", "C19", "C1", "C2", "C20", 
"C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C26", "C27"}

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer.

```
Pick[data, StringStartsQ[data, "C"]]

{"C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", \
"C13", "C18", "C12", "C11", "C9", "C10", "C19", "C1", "C2", "C20", \
"C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C26", "C27"}
```

Comment: Try `Pick[data, StringStartsQ[data, "C"~~DigitCharacter]]` if you want "C" followed by any numeric character. Add "CN1" to `data` for testing. "CN1" must not be in the output.

Comment: Pick[data, StringStartsQ[data, "C"~~DigitCharacter]] works but "CN1" is not working in my case. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"C3", "O3", "H3'", "H3", "C4", "H4A", "H4B", "C5", "C6", "H6",
   "C7", "H7A", "H7B", "C8", "H8", "C14", "H14", "C15", "H15A", 
  "H15B", "C16", "H16A", "H16B", "C17", "H17", "C13", "C18", "H18A", 
  "H18B", "H18C", "C12", "H12A", "H12B", "C11", "H11A", "H11B", "C9", 
  "H9", "C10", "C19", "H19A", "H19B", "H19C", "C1", "H1A", "H1B", 
  "C2", "H2A", "H2B", "C20", "H20", "C21", "H21A", "H21B", "H21C", 
  "C22", "H22A", "H22B", "C23", "H23A", "H23B", "C24", "H24A", "H24B",
   "C25", "H25", "C26", "H26A", "H26B", "H26C", "C27", "H27A", "H27B",
   "H27C"}

Cases[data, _String?(StringMatchQ[StartOfString ~~ "C" ~~ ___])]

DeleteCases[data , _?(StringStartsQ[Except["C"]])]

StringCases[StartOfString ~~ "C" ~~ ___]@data // Flatten

Pick[data, StringMatchQ["C*"][data]]

GroupBy[data, First@*Characters]["C"]
```

---

*Result*

> {"C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", 
> "C13", "C18", "C12", "C11", "C9", "C10", "C19", "C1", "C2", "C20", 
> "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C26", "C27"}